Integrality of a quotient
Consider two positive integers $m$ and $n$ with $m>n$. I would like to prove that the quotient
$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{X^{2^m-2^k}-1}{X^{2^n-2^k}-1}$$
is a polynomial in fact.
What I did is to write its decomposition in irreducible polynomials: let $\Phi_d$ be the $d$-th cyclotomic polynomial. One has
$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{X^{2^m-2^k}-1}{X^{2^n-2^k}-1}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{\prod_{h\mid 2^m-2^k}\Phi_h(X)}{\prod_{l\mid 2^n-2^k}\Phi_l(X)}$$
But I did not manage to conclude. Thanks in advance for any help.

With your work, it suffices to show that $ \prod \frac{ 2^m - 2^k}{2^n -2^k}$ is an integer. Show that this is the number of subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^m$ under some condition, hence is indeed  an integer.

Thanks for your answer. I managed to prove that $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^m-2^k}{2^n-2^k}$ is an integer. But I do not see why it is sufficent to prove the integrability of the quotient.

Oh, I spoke too hastily. We have to ensure the correct powers cancel out. EG $ (\Phi_3)^2 / \Phi_9 $ doesn't work. Hmm...
